# How to cross-compile C++ for aarch64 on an x64 machine with bazel

Tags: cross-compiling, bazel

When attempting this with my project, I follow something like [this tutorial](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html) in order to use a different toolchain but I'm getting a bit swamped in the differences, and it also potentially feels overkill.

**So, taking it back to basics, let's try and cross-compile hello-world with Bazel 1.1.0**

My first naive attempt looks something like:

```
 $ bazel build --cpu=aarch64 //main:hello-world
```

giving the following error:

```
ERROR: /nobackup/marholme/bazel_output_user_root/afdd37b9192d409b599cd579e697b897/external/local_config_cc/BUILD:47:1: in cc_toolchain_suite rule @local_config_cc//:toolchain: cc_toolchain_suite '@loc
al_config_cc//:toolchain' does not contain a toolchain for cpu 'aarch64'
```

Okay, so I need to create a toolchain for the aarch64 cpu. *Note, I'm being a bit lazy here, and am aware of platforms and how they can be used in this context. If I define a platform that has an aarch64 cpu, something similar happens.*

At this point, I feel like I could probably follow instructions [here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/toolchains.html), but we already know cc_toolchain exists, so should leverage [these docs](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html) and the tutorial mentioned previously. This is when I start to get confused. CROSSTOOL means nothing to me, and it's hard to tell, to me at least, what has been deprecated and what is suggested. I have all necessary aarch64-tools (including gcc), but I'm not sure how to let Bazel use them. So, my question is:

**Using cc_toolchain or otherwise, what is the minimal set of changes such that I can create a toolchain that will work?**

Comment: I feel your pain. I'm am very interested in Bazel, but somewhere the Google guys lost site of good docs. The are three major use cases they just don't come on out and answer:

- I'm building c/c++ and wanna use default tool chain stuff but preset some stuff in a single, easy to edit place and otherwise use out of the box stuff e.g. tell Bazel to use clang not gcc and build all my libs and binaries where for x86-32. I don't want to have to re-invent the world here.

- tell me best way to generate debug libraries BUT opt binaries linking those libraries

- a single place to define stuff

Comment: have you been able to cross-compile for aarch64 with bezel with your hello world example successfully?

Comment: In case it's helpful to any of you guys, Bazel 3.3 had an update to the "Configuring C++ Toolchain Tutorial" that was much improved from the previous efforts. I didn't attempt to cross compile, but I did manage to use a different compiler, which I couldn't previously do. Hopefully following this new and improved tutorial would help with setting up an aarch64 based toolchain.